# In ASP.NET, how do I modify POST data and then redirect/POST it to another URL?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have a page that's sending some POST data in plaintext to an aspx page I wrote:

```
firstname: John
lastname: Doe
accountid: 123
```

I need to take this POST data and run it through an encrypting algorithm so the data ends up like so:

```
firstname: AKFJULKHI
lastname: IDKLNZUI
accountid: RIQLKKNIC
```

After encoding it, I then need to POST it to another aspx page that's expecting this encoded data. I cannot modify this page. Essentially, I'm writing an in-between page whose purpose is to take some plaintext data, encode it using a proprietary algorithm, and pass it to another page that expects this encrypted data. I realize it's a useless security feature because the user knows what the data is before the encryption, but I cannot modify the other pages and have to stick to the API.

My question is, what is the easiest way of doing this? `Response.Redirect` will convert it to a GET request, and `Server.Transfer` will not change the URL on the client side. I could do a manual POST request and then do a `Response.Write`, but that seems like a really roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: i think the problem is the other page how to process your sent data,and whether return a message when the other page process success.you can post data in server-side with HttpWebRequest class.it look like the `SSO` architecture.

Comment: The other page is displayed to the user. My page is nothing more than a 'proxy' that adapts the data as it makes its way from page A to page B. It would only be a problem if the other page is intended to be a web service, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP does not support POST redirects.

Instead, you can render a simple page with an HTML form containing hidden inputs with your modified data and pointing to the new URL, then automatically submit the form using Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the way it's being done right now, but it seemed like an incredibly odd hack to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to approach this with a module instead. The HttpModule intercepts the request, can change the request and then the request continues on to the target and the target page is unaware that the request was modified.,

ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers#HttpModuletheeventbasedpreprocessor

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `HttpModule` apply to all requests? I only need the encoding logic to work for one page and adding a HttpModule and doing an if check for this one page on ALL requests seems like a large overhead to me.

Comment: Yes. I suspect it would be cheap perf-wise if you put detect a URL at the top and exit the module if the page isn't the desired page. On the plus side, if this encryption was a good feature to start with, then a module would allow you to add this security feature to all forms.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This encryption is most decidedly a useless feature since the user is able to see the strings before and after encryption, making the encryption worthless. However, we can't change the existing code, so we just have to work around it. I'm a little hesitant to go with the HttpModule method if only because it applies to only one page and would be an unexpected 'feature' for new developers when they try and figure out why the data they're receiving for that particular page is encoded when all the rest are not.

Comment: You may be right, I'm not trying to change your mind, but... the HttpModule would detect the page name and exit/skip processing if the Request.Url wasn't equal to the legacy page. So you might want to look into other solutions, but not because it would require additional code on all other pages (as it wouldn't).